# revert mootools sortable move

Tags: javascript, mootools, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using mootools sortable to handle a simple image gallery function. If you move the image from the left column to the right column, the photo is added into the user's "photos" table by a storeImage call in the onComplete event.

Here's a simple fiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/JQja3/1/

My question is, if the storeImage call from the onComplete event fails, how can I revert the image back to the "available" left stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to store the groups and parents in a var and then revert, this will totally restore the old group and order.

this pattern will create a restore function that can undo it - every time.

http://jsfiddle.net/JQja3/6/

```
new Sortables('#example2 UL', {
    clone: true,
    revert: true,
    opacity: 0.7,
    onStart: function(el, clone) {
        this.restore = (function() {
            var oldParent = el.getParent(),
                oldList = oldParent.getChildren();    
            return function() {
                oldParent.adopt(oldList);
            }
        })();

    },
    onComplete: function(el, clone){
        var storeImage = false; // this is false to simulate a bad return from the DB store call
        if (!storeImage){
            this.restore();
        }       
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 very neat solution, I knew I'd learn something from the answer to this one, took me a good few minutes to get my head round it though, javascript is so different to the other languages I'm used to.

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff-- thanks as always for a quick and thorough solution!